# SSD formating trouble and mysterious disks

Tags: ssd, disk-format

Two days ago suddenly Apple services started to fail on my Mavericks machine. I couldn't shut down (`logind` - or something like that - crashed but could not be force-quit). I shut down twice from terminal. Then I wanted to repair whatever is happening from recovery mode. I don't remember the message but the next thing I know it won't boot anymore.

Now when I use the (internet recovery/DVD) disk utility I usually can't format the SSD (Samsung Evo 840). In these cases sometimes the drive disappears from the Disk Utility (also from Terminal, there's just no /dev/disk0 anymore). Restarting helps, though. Sometimes I can format but then my Time Machine hangs at deleting the disk when restoring. I also took the SSD out and did a long (not the short one) exFAT format on a windows machine. Afterwards I could format it back in the mac to HFS+, but no luck again with the Time Machine. I tried `dd if=/dev/zero` but still the same.

Here's what diskutil gives me right after deleting and creating a new partition with HFS+ and GUID (`disk0` is the SSD, I have no idea what `disk3-12` are but they are multiplying slowly but not consistently during my repair troubles):

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *120.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SSD                     119.7 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *320.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Intern                  319.7 GB   disk1s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.4 GB     disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk2s1
   2:         Apple_Driver_ATAPI                         2.0 KB     disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Mac OS X Base System    1.4 GB     disk2s3
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk3
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk4
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk7
/dev/disk8
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk8
/dev/disk9
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *2.1 MB     disk9
/dev/disk10
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk10
/dev/disk11
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk11
/dev/disk12
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk12
/dev/disk13
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk13
-bash-3.2# diskutil info disk0
   Device Identifier:        disk0
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0
   Part of Whole:            disk0
   Device / Media Name:      Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120GB Media

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 SATA
   SMART Status:             Verified

   Total Size:               120.0 GB (120034123776 Bytes) (exactly 234441648 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                No

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 Yes
   Solid State:              Yes
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

-bash-3.2# diskutil info disk0s2
   Device Identifier:        disk0s2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0s2
   Part of Whole:            disk0
   Device / Media Name:      SSD

   Volume Name:              SSD
   Escaped with Unicode:     SSD

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Volumes/SSD
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Volumes/SSD

   File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                  Journal size 16384 KB at offset 0x37e000
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Partition Type:           Apple_HFS
   OS Can Be Installed:      Yes
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 SATA
   SMART Status:             Verified
   Volume UUID:              4F94E657-2B64-39BE-9762-0B6DCA8189B3

   Total Size:               119.7 GB (119690149888 Bytes) (exactly 233769824 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Volume Free Space:        119.5 GB (119468380160 Bytes) (exactly 233336680 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                No

   Whole:                    No
   Internal:                 Yes
   Solid State:              Yes

-bash-3.2# diskutil info disk12
   Device Identifier:        disk12
   Device Node:              /dev/disk12
   Part of Whole:            disk12
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              9B741394-5571-3C19-9256-98FEDB96157F

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               524.3 KB (524288 Bytes) (exactly 1024 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Volume Free Space:        360.4 KB (360448 Bytes) (exactly 704 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to properly format the disk (and what to do with the `disk4-13`?)

Comment: They are RAM disks to save temporary data and keep OS X running. You are in recovery mode, running from a read-only disk image. Running `mount` command in recovery mode you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

How about the cables/adaptors being used? Are they all fine?
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1702474

But also, before you spend too much time having trouble with a virtually unusable SSD: Hence they have a 3 years warranty, let Samsung give you a new one.